# How to use controller-scoped version of this to refer to the current controller in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I ran into the following problem. My JavaScript structure is like the following.

I created an object that contains all the controllers. Those controllers have their own responsibilities. Below code belongs to the `main.js` file that is called first:

**main.js**

```
var App = {};

App.init = function() {

    console.log('init');

    App.uiController.init();
    App.heroController.init();
    
}
```

Within the function `init()` I call the controllers' initializers.

A controller object looks like the following:

**uiController.js**

```
App.uiController = {
    
    root: 0,
    init: function() {

        // Development
        console.log('init uiController');

        root = this;

        // Call functions
        root.doSomething();

    },

    doSomething: function() {

    }
}
```

After all the scripts are loaded, I call the last script `init.js`:

**init.js**

```
App.init();
```

My HTML markup looks like the following :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- // Start HTML \\ -->
    <header id="header">
    </header><!-- End header#header -->

    <main class="main">     
    </main><!-- End main.main -->

    <footer id="footer">
    </footer><!-- End footer#footer -->



    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <script src="scripts/constructors/uiController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/constructors/heroController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Within the functions I use `root` to select `this` - that file where I currently been. Normally I create the variable `root` in every function (scoped) and give it the value `this`. But I thought this could be better, to create in every controller object one empty root (globally), so I've to only create and add a value once to `root`, like the following:

```
App.uiController = {

    root: 0,
    init: function() {

        root = this;

        // Call functions
        root.doSomething();

    },

    doSomething: function() {

    }
}
```

When I console.log `root` within the `init()` function, it will return an object with all the function that lives within the current controller where I am now, in above example `App.uiController`. So I thought this was working great and I've to create and declare `root` only once for each controllers. So I did the same for `heroController` as I did for `uiController` and log the variable `root` to the console. I receive to different objects with the right functions in it:

[image]

But, here comes the problem. In `main.js` I called `heroController.init()` after `uiController.init()` and When uiController is triggered by an event within the controller, I receive errors in my console that some functions within the `uiController` not working as expect.

When I remove the global `root` variable inside each controller and declare it in the init controllers like `var root = this;` the code will work again.

Why does the above setup not work as I expect?

### UPDATE

Based on the answer from Kingshuk basak, I tried some new things. Here are my thoughts:

The answer code is not working for me. It will give me the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: root is not defined`. When I use the code from my question and change the `root: 0` of the `heroController` to `1` and log both to the console: `console.log(App.uiController.root, App.heroController.root);` I get `0` and `1` in the console. It doesn't matter where I place it in both codes, the values will not be overridden by the other ones. This makes it really strange to me.

Then I tried also comment out `heroController` in `main.js`, then console.log `root` in the `uiController.init() function`. The value that I get back is `0` and that's true, but after that I set `root = this;` and console.log directly after it `root.root` the value will be also `0` and not `this` as the `uiController` object. Which makes it even more confusing, why `root` isn't changing to the object instead of `0`. Also when there is just one `root` in the hole code, after I comment out `heroController.init()` in the file `main.js`. Console.log only `root` will give me the `uiController` object as expected.

Last, I tried also inside both `init()` functions this:

```
root = this;
this.root = root;
console.log('heroController', root);
```

When I do this, the value of `root` is for each controller correct, because it will contain the object - this object - with all the corresponding functions in it. But this will leave me with the same problem as mentioned before, that uiController is not working as expect.

[image: As you can see, both roots inside each controller as different functions]

Comment: Out of your question it is not clear why you need `root` at all. You probably should explain why you need `root`.

Comment: @t.niese it appears that `root` is used as a controller-scoped version of `this` (or `self` or `me` etc that people use) as obviously `this` changes.

Comment: @freedomn-m might be, but then using `bind` or arrow functions (and then transpile if needed)  might be a better choice, but that depends on the actual use-case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Summary

Setting `root` as a property of your controller in order to save you from having to type `var root = this` in your controller methods is not useful. You should just do `var root = this` when needed because the property ultimately is not a net benefit over `var root = this`.

#### Explanation

The first [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38657088/1906307) you got is a partial answer. kingshuk basak is right that what you are doing is setting a `root` variable in the *global space*. See, if you do this:

```
function foo() {
  something =  1;
}
```

you are setting `something` in the global space. To make it local to your function you need `var`:

```
function foo() {
  var something =  1;
}
```

The lack of `var` in the first snippet does not make JavaScript interpret it as `this.something`, even if the function is part of a prototype.

kingshuk basak suggesting you make it part of your controller by using `this`. This works, yes but then **you have to access it using `this`** because that's how JavaScript works. So the naive way to use it would be:

```
uiController = {
  root: 0,
  init: function() {
    this.root = this;
    this.root.doSomething(); // You havve to use `this` here too!!
  },

  doSomething: function() {
     this.root.somethingElse();
  }
}
```

From what your question says, you are just trying to save yourself from having to write `var root = this`. So `root` won't ever change. But think about this for a second.

What you are doing is adding a property named `root` to `this`, which has the exact same value as `this`. In order to access `root`, which has the same value as `this`, you already need to have `this`. So there's no good reason for `this.root` to exist. As explained above, if you do `this.root = this`, then each access to it must be `this.root` so you've not appreciably reduced your burden. Not only that, but doing `this.root.foo()` requires an additional indirection at execution: `root` has to be fetched from `this` first.

You could do this:

```
uiController = {
  root: 0,
  init: function() {
    var root = this.root = this;
    root.doSomething();
  },

  doSomething: function() {
     var root = this.root;
     root.somethingElse();
  }
}
```

But again, this does not reduce the burden.

You should just do `var root = this` when you need it.

Comment: Thank you for the solid answer. In short it's impossible to reduce the burden.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simple. The 'root' variable of the uiController is overWritten by the heroController as both are declared in the global namespace. Try different names as root1 and root2 for uiController and heroController, it will work fine.

Note : Ideally you should not pollute the global namespace to avoid such problems. Use closures if necessary.

This is what you have to do :

```
uiController = {

    root: 0,
    init: function() {

         this.root = this;

        // Call functions
        root.doSomething();

    },

    doSomething: function() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, but when you are in uiController and want to get the root of heroController, you can use `app.heroController.root` to get it's value, so it might be different than `app.uiController.root`. Or isn't this correct? In any case, it sounds logical that you have mentioned above and it makes sense.

Comment: I updated my question with some questions based on you answer. For now it's sadly doesn't work for me... Hope there is a solution for, because it seemed to be a very good and logical one that you give.. @kingshukbasak